# Unable to initialize main class

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to run the following code:

```
public class CountDown {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("T-minus ");
        for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("Blastoff!");
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try to run it, I get this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        String cannot be resolved to a type
        System cannot be resolved
        System cannot be resolved
        System cannot be resolved

        at CountDown.main(CountDown.java:2)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling my jdk but I'm still having the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What exact command are you using to compile and run this? Those classes should be in `java.lang`, which is imported by default and available on every JVM instance.

Comment: If you are using at least Java 11 (eleven), you can run your code without first compiling it. Refer to documentation for [java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html).

Comment: I am using the built in code runner on vscode. @SilvioMayolo

Comment: UPDATE: The issue seems to have resolved itself after one of my extensions updated.